# Ajax Get Request to RestApi

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I'm sure this question has been posted many times before, and I have looked through all related threads. But it's still not working.

We have the JavaScript part:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://localhost:44346/api/persons/",
    //dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (response) {
        callback("a");
    },
    error: function (response) {
        callback("b");
    }
}
);
```

And the C# part:

```
[Route("persons")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetPersons()
{
    return new JsonResult(new { Success = true, Result = "abc" }, 
    System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Problem is the Jquery always has error with result = "b". Breakpoints in the Api are hit. I tried with and without `dataType: "JSON"`. Sending parameters to the Api also works, but getting the result back doesnt work. All projects are .Net 5.0.

Comment: It would be helpful to get the details of the response. The status code and any error messages especially.

Comment: Pls post the controller header too

Comment: response.statusCode.toString() gives: 

f u n c t i o n ( e ) { v a r t ; i f ( e ) i f ( h ) T . a l w a y s ( e [ T . s t a t u s ] ) ; e l s e f o r ( t i n e ) w [ t ] = [ w [ t ] , e [ t ] ] ; r e t u r n t h i s }

Comment: Controller header:

´[ApiController]
    [Route("api")]
    public class PersonController : ControllerBase
    {´

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 url: "https://localhost:44346/api/persons/",
```

with

```
  url: "https://localhost:44346/api/persons",
```

and remove [HttpGet] from your action.

```
[Route("~/api/persons")]
public ActionResult GetPersons()
{
    return new JsonResult(new { Success = true, Result = "abc" });
}
```

But you will stll get error response if APIs CORS is not properly configured.
APIs (not client)  startup should be like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigins", builder =>
            {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                       .AllowAnyMethod()
                       .AllowAnyHeader();
            }));


            services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
            new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
        }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigins");

            //app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
```

Comment: After changing the Url and/or Route the breakpoint was not hit anymore in the Api. Also removing [HttpGet] didnt make any difference.

Comment: @ProgrammingParadise Sorry, I forgot that you are calling API . I made some changes.

Comment: I almost can not believe it. But it works now after 6 hours clicking maybe 300 times. Thanks for saving my day, big thanks!